# Safari Extension Contextmenu Icon and Separator

Tags: javascript, contextmenu, safari-extension

I've searched and can't seem to find a way to add a separator item to my Safari extension contextmenu or to add a custom icon for the regular menu item my extension creates. My contextmenu item is working fine with dynamic text based on the selection but I'd like to differentiate the menu item with either an icon or a separator item (or both) to set it off from menu items from other extensions. Are either of these things possible in Safari extensions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been looking for quite some time and I'm convinced this is not yet possible.